# TSQL OUTPUT clause in MERGE statement raise Msg 596 "Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state"

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I wrote T-SQL `MERGE` query to merge staging data into a data warehouse (you can find it at the bottom).

If I uncomment the `OUTPUT` statement the I get error mentioned in the title.
However, if I do not include it, everything works perfectly fine and `MERGE` succeeds.

I know that there are some issue connected to the `MERGE` clause, however there are more connected to the type of merge.

I checked the following answer: [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140880/why-does-this-merge-statement-cause-the-session-to-be-killed], however in my execution plan I cannot find exactly index insert followed by index merge.

Rather, what I see is [the following execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6vAy.png)

Code was developed on database attached to SQL Server 2012 (SP4) instance

I would really appreciate good explanation of this problem, ideally referencing steps from my execution plan.

Thank you.

```
declare @changes table (chgType varchar(50),Id varchar(18))
begin try
set xact_abort on
begin tran
;with TargetUserLogHsh as (select 
hsh =hashbytes('md5',concat(coalesce([AccountName],'')
      ,coalesce([TaxNumber],'')))
      ,LastLoginCast =  coalesce(CONVERT(datetime,LastLogin,103),getdate())
      ,* from 
      dw.table1)
,SourceUserLogHsh as (select 
hsh =hashbytes('md5',concat(coalesce([AccountName],'')
      ,coalesce([TaxNumber],'')))
      ,LastLoginCast =  coalesce(CONVERT(datetime,LastLogin,103),getdate())
      ,* from 
      sta.table1)

merge TargetUserLogHsh target
using SourceUserLogHsh source
on target.ContactId = source.ContactId and target.Lastlogincast >= source.LastLoginCast
when not matched then  insert (
 [AccountName]
,[TaxNumber]
,[LastLogin]
)
values (
 source.[AccountName]
,source.[TaxNumber]
,source.[LastLogin]
)
when matched and target.lastlogincast = source.lastlogincast
and target.hsh != source.hsh then
update 
set 
 [AccountName] = source.[AccountName]
,[TaxNumber] = source.[TaxNumber]
,[LastLogin] = source.[LastLogin]
output $action,inserted.contactid into @changes
;

commit tran

end try


begin catch

if @@TRANCOUNT > 0 rollback tran

select ERROR_MESSAGE()

end catch
```

Comment: can you please share the merge code snippet used